# Should [tag:systray] and [tag:indicators] merge into [tag:wingpanel]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The current questions in [systray](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systray) and [indicators](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators) have a complete overlap with [wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wingpanel). The only reason why the finer categories may be necessary is if enough questions specifically pertain to individual indicators or different systrays so as to necessitate breaking them out, but I don't see that happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could not see a [indicators](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators) question not pertaining to [wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wingpanel), these have now been merged.